# How do I add custom field to Admin comment form and display

Tags: comments, admin

I am talking about the back-end not the front end of the website. I have added custom fields to my comments on the front end of the site and want to display the results on the back-end. Each comment now has several star ratings that are saved the comment meta system.

I created a custom post type and modified the comment.php file to only add these fields to that post type. When viewing the post on the back-end I am looking for filters or actions that will allow me to modify the following items:

1. Add the custom field to the add comments form within the comments meta box.
2. Display the custom field in the list of comments in the meta box.

No Plugins please.

After many hours of searching there are no answers for this question on google. I dont know if it is even possible.

Comment: So are you doing this for the classic editor?

Comment: No. I am using the gutenberg editor

Comment: How did you add the comments meta box? Can you show a screenshot of it?

Comment: Im talking about the wordpress default comments box.

Comment: Check [this discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gutenberg-missing-comments-section-when-editing-post/) to understand what I mean. And did you really mean the comments **meta box** (on the `wp-admin/post.php` page) and not the `wp-admin/edit-comments.php` page for the specific post?